# Finding a path through a checkerboard which is closest to a given cost

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've been stuck on a problem for a while. I am in an algorithm course right now but this isn't a homework problem. We haven't gotten to dynamic programming in class yet, I'm just doing this on my own.

> Given a NxN sized checkerboard where every coordinate has a cost and another integer M, find the cost of a path from the top left of the checkerboard to the bottom right of the checkerboard (only allowed moves are right or down 1 square) such that the total cost of the path is below M but as close to M as possible. All elements of NxN and M are positive.

If this asked me to find the minimum or maximum path, I could use the standard dynamic programming algorithms but since I'm bounded by M, I think I have to use another strategy. I've been trying to use memoization and construct an array filled with a set of the cost of all possible paths from the start to a given element. To construct the set for (i, j),  I add the cost value of (i, j) to every element in the union of the the sets for (i-1, j) and (j-1, i) (if they exist, else just use the set {0} in its place). Once I complete this for all elements in the checkerboard, choosing the right path is trivial. Just pick the element in the set for (N, N) which is below M but closest to M.

For example:

```
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

Cost of paths to a given point:

```
+---+----------+----------------+
| 0 | 1        | 4              |
| 3 | 3, 5     | 4, 5, 6        |
| 8 | 5, 7, 10 | 5, 6, 7, 8, 11 |
+---+----------+----------------+
```

This is a really space inefficient way of doing things. If I did the math right, the worst case scenario for the number of elements in the set of the (N, N) node is (N+1)!/((N+1)/2)!. Is there a faster (space or time) way of approaching this problem that I'm missing?

Comment: Can the cost be negative?

Comment: No. All costs in the grid and M will be positive. It is possible for the minimum cost for a path through the grid to be greater than M (in which case the answer is that there is no path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If all the costs are integers, at each cell you need to store at most O(M) elements. So you need O(MN^2) memory. If the sum is >M you just ignore it.

In this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677401912015) there is a mention of a pseudo polynomial algorithm to solve similar problem (exact cost). You can either use same algorithm multiple time with exact cost = M..1, or maybe read the algorithm and find a variation that solves your problem directly.

Unfortunately that paper is paywalled :(

Comment: That's indeed true when the costs are positive, which OP confirmed.